# Nextjs - I can't access the site

Tags: docker, next.js

I can't access the site.

I only get redirects.

Req example:

```
General:
Request URL: domain.com
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 Not Modified
Referrer Policy: strick-origin-when-cross-origin




Response Headers:

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 07 Nov 2023 09:04:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: RSC, Next-Router-State-Tree, Next-Router-Prefetch, Next-Url, Accept-Encoding
x-nextjs-cache: STALE
X-Powered-By: Next.js
Cache-Control: s-maxage=1, stale-while-revalidate
ETag: "10t5g8r5i88qw0"
Content-Encoding: gzip

Request Headers:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: __stripe_mid=d6b3c999-5bf7-4671-b42f-73748d22b59a2b94c5; __stripe_sid=ac632eb4-ad3e-4a89-996c-66039edadbbca59e9b
Host: eklix.cbdevs.com
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
```

NextJS build is inside Docker, [production mode.](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker-multi-env/docker/production)

Log in prod mode:

```
 ⚠ Entire page / deopted into client-side rendering. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering /


Error: The render was aborted by the server without a reason.
    at eM (node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page-experimental.runtime.prod.js:107:15717)
    at Object.cancel (node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page-experimental.runtime.prod.js:107:27343)
```